# What is mean by the term "an organism's genotype is its specific combination of alleles for a given gene"?

Tags: genetics

> an organism's genotype is its specific combination of alleles for a given gene

What is meant by this? Is it talking about heterozygous and homozygous (like GG or Gg) or is it talking about the nuclear bases?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no source given for the fragment quoted.

Answer (score 3):

From wikipedia

> An [Allele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) is a variant form of a given gene.

Let's consider a simplified example. There is a gene for eye color and there are different alleles at this gene. The allele for blue eye, the allele for brown eye etc...

In a diploid (see [ploidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy)) individual (humans are diploid), we have two copies of each gene (exception of sex chromosomes). Let's imagine, at a givne gene, there are 3 possible alleles called `A`, `B` and `C`. The possible combinations are

```
AA
AB
AC
BB
BC
CC
```

The genotype of an individual for a given gene (I should say [locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus) for the sake of generality) is called the genotype of an individual.

> Is it talking about heterozygous and homozygous[?]

The terms "homozygous" or "heterozygous" are adjectives to define whether, in a diploid genotype, the same allele is found on both haplotypes or not. In the above examples, 3 genotypes are homozygous (`AA`, `BB` and `CC`) and 3 genotypes are heterozygous (`AB`,`AC` and `BC`).

> [I]s it talking about the nuclear bases?

For two alleles to be different, they must differ in their sequence of nuclear bases of course.

Answer (score 1):

Alleles are different versions of the same gene; they have different nucleotide sequences. Which versions of each gene an organism gets defines its genotype.

Zygosity (heterozygous/homozygous) is a related idea. When creatures have more than one copy of a chromosome (e.g. one from each parent) the alleles of each gene on each chromosome may be the same (homozygous) or different (heterozygous).